# how to programmatically set the path for browse button on reuse slide pane and open file open dialog, for reusing slide in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

i am working on VSTO -  powerpoint 2016. i am able to open the reuse slide pane programmatically by

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("SlidesReuseSlides");
```

this code of lines. but now

> I need to set the path to file open dialog of browse button of reuse slide pane. so, when browse button get clicked then given path destination folder will get open and user will select PPT file from there.

Please suggest how to set the path programmatically for browse button (file open dialog) on reuse slide pane of powerpoint in **c# vsto.**

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: (1). create a ribbon on powerpoint. and on the click event on it, paste the above code. this is a powerpoint vsto project in c# vs2017. (2).after click ribbon the reuse task will pane appear. then u can anyalise my question.